# Loop through PHP array based on index

Tags: php, arrays

How can I assign values to an array of strings using an index? Let's say I don't know what the values of the strings are in the array, so I use keys instead.

**Array that could be any list of strings:**

```
$this->cols = array(
    'name',
    'age'
);
```

**assignment function**

```
$row = 1;
        if (($f = fopen($this->file['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
          while (($data = fgetcsv($f, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                $row++;
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $colName = $this->cols[$c];
                    $this->cols[$colName] = $data[$c];
                }
            }
```

How can I assign the value ($data[$c]) to the corresponding index if I don't supply its value, but rather use a numerical index? I know for a fact that I can access the array like this because

```
$colName[0] = 'name'
$colName[1] = 'age'
```

But when I run the function I get

```
0 => nameValue
1 => ageValue
```

Instead of

```
'name' => nameValue
'age' => ageValue
```

Comment: What is $f? Where does it come from?

Comment: I suggest you start looking into the php documentation. There you will find a wealth of array handling functions. All explained in details including examples.

Comment: The main problem I see is too many things happening at the same time. Try to separate the part where you read the file from the loop of it, then the assignment of the variables from the loop. In this way every bug/problem will be much easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your own data:

```
 $num = count($data);
 $row++;
 for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
     // every row of the CSV will update the same keys
     $colName = $this->cols[$c];
     $this->cols[$colName] = $data[$c];

 }

 // I suggest adding a `break` after that for look to see the problem.
 break;
```

Alternatively, you could update the code to track all values:

```
 $num = count($data);
 $row_val = array();
 $this->cols[] = $row_val;
 $row++;
 for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
     // every row of the CSV will update the same keys
     $colName = $this->col_names[$c];
     $row_val[$colName] = $data[$c];

 }
```

Comment: You're probably right but I haven't gotten that far yet. I just wanted to understand how to assign a value to an array based on indexes.

Comment: OK so the answer is make a new array to assign the values. Thanks.

Comment: actually the OP was not overriding..he was appending to the array. when i ran this code i got 4 elements with 0,1,name, age keys.